# How to add request header to specific domain only in Angular 6 Interceptor

Tags: angular6, angular-routing

I'm using `Angular 6`.

My application needs to call multiple domain urls, one of them is the main server url which needs to add Authorization headers and others do not need to add headers.

I have created an Interceptor class to handle adding Authorization headers to the request.

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http'; 
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; 
import {AuthService} from './auth.service'; 
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 

@Injectable() 
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {   

    constructor(     
        public Auth: AuthService   
    ) { }   

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {   
      console.log(this.Auth.accessToken());    
      console.log('inside interceptor');  
      request = request.clone({       
          setHeaders: {       
               'Accept': 'application/json',         
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': `${this.Auth.tokenType()} ${this.Auth.accessToken()}`
           }
     });

     return next.handle(request);
   }
 }
```

But this is adding headers to all urls.

How can I add headers only to specific url like.

```
https://server.mydomain.com
```

The headers should be added only when domain os `mydomain.com` otherwise no headers added in request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use location.hostname to check domain, something like this...

```
if(location.hostname === 'some.domain.com') {   
  request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',         
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `${this.Auth.tokenType()} ${this.Auth.accessToken()}`
    }   
  }); 
} else {   
  request = request.clone({setHeaders: {}}); 
}
```

Comment: `location.hostname` gives hostname of the domain on which angular application is running. In my case, it gives localhost since the application is running locally.

Comment: Instead of using `location.hostname`. I used `request.url` and then parsed the url to get hostname using `new URL('')`